# Multiple offsets.topic.replication.factor in kafka-cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

I know that offsets.topic.replication.factor parameter is given server.properties on broker.

Can I create one of the topics as:

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
```

and the other as:

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor = 2
```

in the kafka-cluster?

I have 3 zookeper, 3 broker, and my cluster replication factor=2.

Comment: Replication factor can be defined at topic level.

Comment: kafka-topics.sh --create \
  --topic my-topic \
  --replication-factor 2 \  // <-- define replication factor
  --partitions 4 \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181

Comment: @sun That replication factor is different than the setting mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one consumer offsets topic for the entire Kafka cluster that gets auto-created when the cluster starts.

The setting must be the same on each broker, and `offsets.topic.replication.factor` cannot be set at a topic level

This setting is different than the `default.replication.factor`, and you should really disable auto topic creation and specify those replication factors when creating topics manually